# Use Jquery in Aurelia with Typescript

Tags: jquery, node.js, typescript, aurelia

I'm using Aurelia with typescript, using aurelia-cli and npm as build system and client side package manager. My goal is to use jquery within one of my .ts files, so I have added jquery through

```
npm install jquery@2.2.4 --save
```

and after it for typings I used :

```
typings install dt~jquery --global --save
```

I also configured aurelia.json file with "jquery" as vendor bundle dependency.

Using :

```
import * as jq from 'jquery';
```

but the project failed to build with the following errors :

`Starting 'readProjectConfiguration'...
Finished 'readProjectConfiguration'
Starting 'processMarkup'...
Starting 'processCSS'...
Starting 'configureEnvironment'...
Finished 'processCSS'
Finished 'processMarkup'
Finished 'configureEnvironment'
Starting 'buildTypeScript'...
typings/globals/jquery/index.d.ts(3218,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '$' must be of type 'cssSelectorHelper', but here has type 'JQueryStatic'.
[17:45:00] gulp-notify: [Error running Gulp] Error: typings/globals/jquery/index.d.ts(3218,13): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '$' must be of type 'cssSelectorHelper', but here has type 'JQueryStatic'.`

so what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue and is caused by a clash between jQuery and Protractor type definitions.

See [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/2734) and [here](https://github.com/aurelia/cli/issues/301).

Both declare '$' as a global. Protractor uses $('css')  as a shortcut selector which causes a clash with jQuery.

There are a couple of workarounds - the first two are to rename the declarations for either Protractor or jQuery (which is what the first two answers here do for jQuery). If you'd rather leave jQuery with '$' then rename the Protractor global. You'll find the declaration in `your-project-directory\typings\globals\angular-protractor\index.d.ts` (well this is the location in my Aurelia + gulp/jspm project). Look for the the line `declare var $: cssSelectorHelper;` and edit or comment it out completely.

Alternatively, if you are not going to use Protractor then remove it from your project entirely.

If you need Protractor and jQuery then try uninstalling the Protractor typings (thus removing the Protractor global declaration) - [see this article at aureliajsrocks.com](http://www.aureliajsrocks.com/error-variable-must-type-cssselectorhelper/). This article also points out that this is just a transpiler error:

> Although Protractor declares a $ variable that conflicts with jQuery,
>   you don’t actually load Protractor into memory when running your app.
>   So there is no conflict with jQuery during runtime.
>
> The problem occurs because the Protractor TypeScript definition file
>   is global and is loaded by the transpiler even if the actual .js
>   library itself isn’t being loaded....

If you need to have jQuery and run Protactor tests then right now this looks like the best solution, hopefully this will get resolved or if anyone has a better solution then please share...

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change the jquery d.ts module declaration to  :

```
declare module "jquery" {
    export var $:JQueryStatic;
    export var jquery:JQueryStatic
}
```